# Getting error "No visible @interface for 'CIImage' declares the selector 'size'" on a pre iOS 7 project that was previously working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can't compile a legacy app in my org that was previously running and getting the following error but not having any luck debugging it. (I'm not much of an Obj-C dev).

This is the function we're having issues with:

```
static CGSize newSizeWithFont(NSString *self, SEL _cmd, UIFont *font)
{
  if ([self cxa_doesWrapInvisibleIdentifiers] &&
      titleSettingsPairs[self]){
    CGSize size = [[titleSettingsPairs[self] image] size];
    size.width -= [titleSettingsPairs[self] shrinkWidth];
    return size;
  }

  return origSizeWithFont(self, _cmd, font);
}
```

and again

```
static CGSize newSizeWithAttributes(NSString *self, SEL _cmd, NSDictionary *attributes)
{
  if ([self cxa_doesWrapInvisibleIdentifiers] &&
      titleSettingsPairs[self]){
    CGSize size = [[titleSettingsPairs[self] image] size];
    size.width -= [titleSettingsPairs[self] shrinkWidth];
    return size;
  }

  return origSizeWithAttributes(self, _cmd, attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're usinsg a  `CIImage`, to access the size of a `CIImage` you should use `extent.size`

For example

```
CGSize size=someCIImage.extent.size;
```